# Google Play Console (Play Market) - Hi-res icon (App Status: Rejected)

Tags: android, google-play, icons, google-developers-console

This is the error message I get when attempting to give my app an image on the play store.
Here are the Google Play requirements:
Final size: 512px x 512px
Format: 32-bit PNG
Color space: sRGB
Max file size: 1024KB
Shape: Full square
Shadow: None

Here is the image metadata:
ImageWidth: 512
ImageHeight: 512
BitDepth: 8 8 8 8
DeviceModel: sRGB
ProfileDescription: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
ColorType: RGB with Alpha
FileSize: 468 KiB
Shape: Full square
Shadow: None
**IMAGE**: https://prnt.sc/j17BwhIGFZTo

I saved the file through Gimp and through Photoshop and through Paint.net, my icon is constantly rejected.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic